# How to use the Laravel Scheduler on shared hosting?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-scheduler

My hoster technically allows cronjob but with the limitation to php files.

There is no way to access the crontab from a console.

I can set it up in the administration UI only and I need to provide a path to a php file. My ssh user has now access to the crontab. `php artisan` commands are working.

How can I set the recommended `* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` in a php file? Or more strict:
How can I run `php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` from a php file, so that I can provide this file to the administration UI?

Comment: no, not from a php file.  Artisan is the php file that your provider allows you to run.  You just need to find the two paths, one to php itself and one to the artisan script.

Comment: Okay that's easy but when I have the paths, what do I do with them?

Comment: What method do you need to use to configure cron?

Comment: As written in my question, there is only the administration ui where I just can specify a path to a php file and set the timing.

Comment: ok so your path is the path of artisan and the timing is every minute

Comment: I don't understand. I must provide a path to a *.php file

Comment: artisan is a php file

Comment: I am not really sure if you understood my issue. If you do, maybe you can right a short answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So on the basis that you can only execute a php script in the particular cron setup of your host;

You can create a file as follows to only run the `schedule:run` artisan command;

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader
| for our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll require it
| into the script here so that we do not have to worry about the
| loading of any of our classes manually. It's great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Artisan Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When we run the console application, the current CLI command will be
| executed in this console and the response sent back to a terminal
| or another output device for the developers. Here goes nothing!
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);

$input = new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;

$status = $kernel->call('schedule:run', [], new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Shutdown The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once Artisan has finished running, we will fire off the shutdown events
| so that any final work may be done by the application before we shut
| down the process. This is the last thing to happen to the request.
|
*/

$kernel->terminate($input, $status);

exit($status);
```

This is adapted from the `artisan` file itself but removes the ability to specify anything other than `schedule:run`

create this file as `scheduler.php` in the root of your project and then call this from your hosts cron setup with * * * * * as the time pattern (every minute).  You might need to prefix it with the path to your project.

Comment: Your setup is working but not to the final end. I can't set a `* * * * *` cron line in the hosting UI, but there is a drop down for "every X minutes" and I can provide a 1. I now added a `info("Test");` in `app/Console/Kernel.php` to see, if it gets fired and it does. But the actual scheduled command does not get fired. I have `$schedule->command('test:run')->withoutOverlapping();` and in the job I have a second log that does not get printed. When I run `php scheduler.php` in the command line, then it I see both logs. Any idea?

Comment: you may need to change it from a command to a direct call to the class containing the action you want to perform.  $schedule-.command is probably trying to spawn a new thread.